# How to turn "TIMEVALUE" result into time amount?

Tags: excel

Hey I want to know if there are a way to manipulate "timevalue" function results more easily. What I want to know if there is a way to turn time value into time amount. To be clear let me give you an example, let say we have two values 0.629167 *(which is 15:06:00)* and 0.75 *(which is 18:00:00)* and I want to find the time difference *(which is 18:00:00 - 15:06:00 = 02:54:00)* from timevalue result which is *0.75-0.629167 = 0.120833*
And when looking at the cells I don't want to see am and pm :D

Comment: Just change the number format on the result cell(s) to "Number"

Comment: @Marc wow, thank you. That was easy :)